# Migrated email (and thus calendar) from Gmail to Fastmail - possible to accept calendar invites forwarded from Gmail within Fastmail UI?

Tags: google-calendar

I recently switched email provider to Fastmail from Gmail. When I receive event invites to my old Gmail, which are forwarded to my Fastmail, I cannot accept the meeting without logging into Google Calendar first (or logging into Gmail).

Screen of a Calendar invite within Gmail where you can click 'Yes' to accept the invite:
[image]

I want to share the same invite in Fastmail but cannot without showing email addresses. In Fastmail UI there is no 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe' option to respond with. Instead, there's an attached 'invite.ics' file.

Is there a way to accept meeting invites that are still sent to my Gmail where those invites are forwarded to my Fastmail?

Note I have both my calendars shared. In Fastmail my Gmail calendar events do show. It's specifically the response tot he invite I'm struggling with, I want to let the other party know that I have accepted or declined the invite from within Fastmail, if it's possible?